Getting error "non-top-level require() call" with no require() beign used
I'm trying to move a web made with vanilla JS to node.js and I'm getting this error using Parcel2:
@parcel/transformer-js: Conditional or non-top-level `require()` call. This causes the resolved module and all dependencies to be wrapped.

  C:\Users\xxx\zabbix_console.js:1:1
  > 1 | import { sendNotification, fetchResource, clipboardCopy, ENDPOINT, getSetting, saveSetting } from "../libs/utils.js";
  >   | ^
    2 | import { getUserData } from "../libs/login.js";
    3 | import  {EVENT_TYPE } from "../libs/events.js";

  ℹ Learn more: https://parceljs.org/features/scope-hoisting/#avoid-conditional-require()

@parcel/core: Asset graph walked
@parcel/core: Asset graph walked
- Building runtime-9b535c67382b3742.js...

But the problematic file is not using require() anywhere, also it's dependencies. The file utils.js has this at the top:
import { EVENT_TYPE } from "./events.js";

export const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8080";

...

events.js doesn't use any import whatsoever, so I don't know where the error is...
Things I've tried, from searching on the web:

Renaming the extension to .mjs
Setting the target in package.json and telling it is a esmodule.
Using type: module in package.json.
Deleting .parcel-cache and rebuiding.
Using .parcelrc to tell what transformers to use for .js/.mjs files.

I don't have much experience with this, so I'm kinda stuck.
EDIT 11/25
Seems like adding --no-optimize to the build command, compiles the code... I'm still getting the require() error, but everything compiles. I still don't know why.

I could never find the why to this, so I fixed it by switching to Parcel v1 and no more errors. Works better and faster, at least for what I was trying to achieve.
